# Eclipse: what's the proper way to export a plugin as a product?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, export

I created an eclipse product based on a plugin.

[image: http://imgur.com/0TncNrH]

from the product pane:

- left side, pressing "Launch an eclipse application" invokes a new eclipse platform that is only able to create an empty project or a project based on my plugin (no java project, etc...). OK that is what I want.
- right side: I've exported my product in a fresh empty directory. When I run my application from the command-line, I'm asked to open a new workspace and then, I only get an empty window .

what's the proper way to export my application ?

Thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your export doesn't work is that you select org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench. 
When you generated your EMF code as RCP. (This is an option in the .genmodel under Editor->Rich Client Plarform) you should get an application for the RCP. When you select this application in your .product, all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your product configuration: go to the "dependencies" tab and press the "Add Required" button.
2. If you would like to export your plugin (product) as a standalone application(just create a build) I would recommend you to take a look at the Tycho (http://eclipse.org/tycho/). Tycho tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html.